# How to send xml request using SOAP in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, soap

I'm trying to integrate with one API and they provide xml response. I've never used SOAP and I'm new learner in JS. Here is what they have as a function:

```
'<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ' + 
          'xmlns:pac="http://ws.sanmar.com/webservices/PackingSlip">' +
          '<soapenv:Header/>' +
          '<soapenv:Body>' +
          '<pac:GetPackingSlip>' +
          '<pac:wsVersion>1.0.0</pac:wsVersion>' +
          '<pac:UserId>"someString"</pac:UserId>' +
          '<pac:Password>"someString"</pac:Password>' +
          '<pac:PackingSlipId>someNumber</pac:PackingSlipId>';
```

then they will have an XML response.
I don't know how to send this request in my html or js file. here is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
<title>Receiving App</title>
<head>
  <title>SOAP JavaScript Client Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function soap() {
          var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlhttp.open('POST', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/', true);

     
          var sr =
          '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ' + 
          'xmlns:pac="http://ws.sanmar.com/webservices/PackingSlip">' +
          '<soapenv:Header/>' +
          '<soapenv:Body>' +
          '<pac:GetPackingSlip>' +
          '<pac:wsVersion>1.0.0</pac:wsVersion>' +
          '<pac:UserId>"MyUsername"</pac:UserId>' +
          '<pac:Password>"MyPass"</pac:Password>' +
          '<pac:PackingSlipId>LP0063137305</pac:PackingSlipId>';

          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                  if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                      alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    
                  }
              }
          }

          xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
          xmlhttp.send(sr);

      }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <p>Your barcode:</p>
    <div id= "last-barcode"></div>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!-- <p>here is the info:<span id= 's'></span></p> -->

    <form name="Demo" action="" method="post">
      <div>
          <input type="button" value="Soap" onclick="soap();" />
      </div>
  </form>
    <!-- <script src="j.js"></script> -->

  </body>
</html>
```

the commented out parts are not related to my question.
could you please tell me what is wrong and give me some advice? BTW, here is the error that I get in console:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
i.html:34

POST http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ net::ERR_FAILED